# Passing constants to TIniFile.ReadString

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe5, c++builder-tokyo

Do I have to use **L** each time I pass a cosntant to ReadString?

```
s = MyIni->ReadString (L"ü", L"SomeEntry", "");
```

The Embarcadero example doesn't say so, but they also don't use non-ASCII characters in their example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++Builder 2009 and later, the entire RTL is based on `System::UnicodeString` rather than `System::AnsiString`.  Using the `L` prefix tells the compiler to create a **wide** string literal (based on `wchar_t`) instead of a **narrow** string literal (based on `char`).

While you don't HAVE to use the prefix `L`, you SHOULD use it, because it invokes less overhead at runtime.  On Windows, constructing a `UnicodeString` from a `wchar_t` string is just a simple memory copy, whereas constructing it from a `char` string performs a data conversion (using the `System::DefaultSystemCodePage` variable as the codepage to use for the conversion).  That conversion *MAY* be lossy for non-ASCII characters, depending on the encoding of the **narrow** string, which is subject to the charset that you save your source file in, as well as the charset used by the compiler when it parses the source file.  So there is no guarantee that what you write in code in a **narrow** string literal is what you will actually get at runtime.  Using a **wide** string literal avoids that ambiguity.

Note that `UnicodeString` is UTF-16 encoded on all platforms, but `wchar_t` is used for UTF-16 only on Windows, where `wchar_t` is a 16-bit data type.  On other platforms, where `wchar_t` is usually a 32-bit data type used for UTF-32, `char16_t` is used instead.  As such, if you need to write portable code, use the RTL's `_D()` macro instead of using the `L` prefix directly, eg:

```
s = MyIni->ReadString(_D("ü"), _D("SomeEntry"), _D(""));
```

`_D()` will map a string/character literal to the correct data type (`wchar_t` or `char16_t`, depending on the platform you are compiling for).  So, when using string/character literals with the RTL, VCL, and FMX libraries, you should get in the habit of always using `_D()`.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Follow up question: Why do you have to use _D also on empty string ("") ?

Comment: @Rigel for the same reason as the other strings. Even an empty string has a data type. Best to always use the same data type that `UnicodeString` prefers, even for empty strings. It avoids invoking the data conversion routines at runtime